# I have a for counting occurrences of a letter but can only count from 1 to 9

Tags: javascript, for-loop, character, counting

I have two inputs (original and comprimida). The original one is like this one "bbbddef" which in a compressed form would be "b3d2e1f1" (Three times b, two times d, one for e and one for f). However, when I have a original like this one: "aaaaaaaaaaabcdda" that should be "a11b1c1d2a1" it only counts till 9 because the for cannot go above 9 (two digits). How can I solve this? Thanks in advance.

Here's the code

```
var original = "aaaaaaaaaaabcdda";
var comprimida = "a11b1c1d2a1";
var res = "";

for(var i = 0; i < comprimida.length; i+=2){
    let letra = comprimida.charAt(i);
    let numero = comprimida.charAt(i+1);
    for(let j=0; j<numero; j++){
        res += letra;
    }
}

if(original == res){
    alert("SI");
} else {
    alert("NO");
}
```

The code should do 'a' 11 times and it's not doing so since it only takes the first 1 from 11. But I can't make it count two digits only because then every other solution for 'a' being less than 10 would be wrong.

Comment: What have you tried, where is the problem? You present code, which digests strings in blocks of two `i+=2`, one letter, followed by one digit, both taken as single characters with `charAt`. "a11" is certainly not such a block. Now what? I understand the task, but where did you get stuck?

Comment: Instead of original = "aaaaaaaaaaabcdda" and comprimida = "a11b1c1d2a1". Let's use original = "aaabcdda" and comprimida = "a3b1c1d2a1". Output will be YES, which is right. If we go back to a11 instead of a3 output will be NO. Which is wrong, should be YES.

Comment: `const res = comprimida.replace(/(\D)(\d+)/g, (_, l, n) => l.repeat(Number(n)));`, maybe this will show you the issue, when it's unclear, where your problem is - my glass ball tells me this will just open a whole bag of new questions.

Comment: You need to check for multiple digits after the letter, not just `charAt(i+1)`.

Comment: @Barmar and how can I do that? Thanks

Comment: @ASDFGerte This solution works but I think it's too complex for my level. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution reads char by char. If it's a letter it is being remembered, if it's a digit it's being calculated to be a number. Then, if it's a letter again we repeat number of times the last remembered letter.

```js
var comprimida = "a11b1c1d2a1";
var result = "";
var current = "";
var number = 0;

comprimida.split("").forEach(function(char) {
  if (char >= 'a' && char <= 'z') {
    result += current.repeat(number)
    number = 0;
    current = char;
  } else {
    number = number * 10 + +char
  }
})
result += current.repeat(number)
console.log(result)
```